# Mysql Query getting slower due to IN clause. Any possible alternatives?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have 2 mysql tables "store (id,name,imageurl)" and "favorites(person,storeid)" .

Everything was working fine. But its getting slower as data is increasing. I think its mainly due to the 'IN' in the query. Is there any ways to make this query some more smarter in execution?

```
SELECT id,name,imageurl FROM store WHERE id IN 
(SELECT storeid FROM favorites WHERE person='rhino' AND storeid>100000)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternate approach

It looks like you can just do a direct lookup instead of the `IN`. Something like this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.imageurl 
FROM store s, favorites f 
WHERE f.person='rhino' AND f.storeid>100000 AND f.storeid=s.id
```

This approach avoids a `JOIN`, which could be expensive too.

Comment: Thanks. Its working super fast and real smart for me. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the join syntax. No need for a sub-query here

```
SELECT store.id, store.name, store.imageurl
  FROM store
  JOIN favorites ON store.id = favorites.storeid
  WHERE favorites.person = 'rhino' AND store.id > 100000
```

You should use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) to get an idea of your queries performance.

Comment: Thanks to @tadman for the edit. The reference to explain was added by him

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
store.id,
store.name,
store.imageurl

FROM store
INNER JOIN favorites
    ON store.id = favorites.storeid
    AND favorites.person = 'rhino'

WHERE store.id > 100000
```

It's basically about optimising the query - a JOIN is better than a nested select in this instance.

You'll probably also want to ensure you've got INDEXes on `favorites.storeid` and `favorites.person` since you have JOIN and WHERE conditions on them.